# Requesting your help to identify what is automatically executed when a QGIS layer is saved

Tags: qgis, sqlite

I'm working with a QGIS project where a script runs during the saving process. I've looked extensively, but I haven't been able to locate the code that gets executed.

I believe the layers are saved in SQLite format, but I'm uncertain about how to work with this file format.

Could someone provide guidance on what happens when the 'TEST' layer is saved and how I can access and view the associated code?"

If you want to see the behavior of the layer, I suggest you do the following:

- use the tool "Separate entities"
- for one of the two entities, in the attribute table, enter "A2.2" in the second field ("1 - Code EUNIS").
- save the layer.

Several fields will be automatically updated.

Here is a link to download the test project if you want to check.

[Project](https://fromsmash.com/TestLayerAutoCompleted)

Edit:

Macro:
[image: Macro]

Comment: I don't get what code/script you are talking about. This question probably needs a more clear question statement. When you say "save the layer" is it "right-click layer > Export > Save Features As ..." or something done in the script/code you mention or something entirely different?

Comment: I don't really know if there is a script executed. But what I'm sure is that the layer is updated. Several fields are filled with codes. When I say "save the layer" I mean save the modification (ctrl+S). Every time I save the modification, the layer is updated. But I can't find any action, expression, script, etc. that is executed. And no information in the message log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a QGIS script but some triggers in the SpatiaLite database. As the action is at the database level it will work on any computer and doesn't require any specific input from the software interacting with the database (other than editing the data).

To see what happen use the DB manager to connect to your SpatiaLite database and look in the info tab, you will find the list of triggers that apply to the selected layer (these are SQL expression that are executed after specific action like insert and update) .

[image]

Comment: This is it ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no code in QGIS that would automatically update the table. A plugin code could though.

A layer can be defined to update some of its fields when saving. Right click the layer / `properties` / `attributes form` then select the field and scroll down to the `default` section

[image]

Comment: Indeed, this is how it works usually. In my case, there are no constraint (but one field still has a constraint) and there are no default values, but some fields are calculated after saving. This is not a plugin, I can copy and paste this project and use it on any computer with QGIS, it will always work the same. I'm very surprised that a layer can update itself without giving any information anywhere in QGIS... By the way, it works offline.

Comment: Is there anything in `project`/`properties`/`macros`?

Comment: Nothing, I added a picture in my first post to show its content. Same if I tick the "Macro Python" checkbox